# Configuring a VPN on a router for a single IP address

Tags: router, vpn, ip-address, private-browsing, ps4

So I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I thought I'd give it a shot anyway. I use private Internet access VPN on my laptop, phone etc. I wish to use it on my PS4 too.

Now, I am aware that this can be done a number if ways, the best either being directly connected with a crossover cable to the laptop, or having the VPN set up on the router. I much prefer the sound of having it set up on the router.

However, is it possible to have a single IP address using the VPN? For example, if the PlayStation had a static ip address of 192.168.0.10, could I configure the VPN on the router, just for the device with this IP address? Or a particular address range?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need a router that supports Policy Based routing. You'll setup a rule that routes traffic through the VPN interface according to the source IP address.

Here's an example using [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Policy_Based_Routing)